# Powerpoint saves files after just viewing

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, version-control, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

If i open a .ppt file in Powerpoint 2007 and then just close it without modifying anything the file will be saved/modified by powerpoint. (.pptx doesnt seem to be affected)

This is very annoying as versioning systems detects it as a file change and promts for commit or notifies all other colleagues depending on system used.  I don't want to notify the whole team that I've just read a document and they surely don't want to get notified about it either thinking it has been updated.

Is there any way to disable this behavior? And what's the rationale behind it in the first place?!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where the .ppt files are saved, but can't you just open them in read-only mode?
Since you can't change anything, I'd think Powerpoint won't ask you to save.

Answer (score 1):

I agree this is very annoying behaviour.

My usual workaround is to make a quick copy of the file in the version control system working directory with select-file, CTRL-C, CTRL-V, and then edit the copied file to view it.

By default, version control systems such as SVN / Tortoise will usually ignore additional uncontrolled files like these.

Answer (score 0):

Powerpoint may be set up to autosave at regular intervals. This is useful if you are editing but not, apparently, if you only wish to view the file. This can be deselected but, unfortunately, I don't have 2007 on this PC so I can't talk you through it.

Comment: My problem is not because of autosave. This is something else. Autosave only triggers if you've actually made any changes and every 10min. This save occurs even if you've just had the document open for a few seconds. I will try to disable it anyway and get back with the results.